# Tensor flow predicts very odd results

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

Am I trying to train an Ai to predict a value between `1`and `0`
The  training data looked like this:
[image]

I shuffled the data with 
`df = df.sample(frac=1)`
and checked that it only changed the rows position.
After that I removed the left columns with the name “Label” with 
`df_Label = df.pop("Label")`
I splited the data with \

```
`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)
train_Labels, test_Labels = train_test_split(df_Label, test_size=0.2)
`
```

And normalized it with

```
`train = train / 15
test = test / 15
`
```

My Sequential Tensor-flow model looks like this:\

```
model_8 = tf.keras.Sequential([
                     tf.keras.layers.Dense(41, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
                     tf.keras.layers.Dense(40, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
                     tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid)
])
model_8.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model_8.fit(train, train_Labels, validation_data=(test, test_Labels), epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

The last epoch verbose looks like this: 
`485/485 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0130 - accuracy: 0.9983 - val_loss: 0.0116 - val_accuracy: 0.9985`

So I would think that it did pretty well, even on the validations set, but when I tried to predict with it:
`prediction = model_8.predict(liste)` 
`print(prediction)`  \

> liste is just a random row minus the last column transformed into a pd Dataframe.

With output: 
`[[6.131363e-27]]`
It should have been `0`\

### What am I doing wrong

I mean, even if everything went wrong, I only gave my models `1`and `0`as possible results. How would it predict `6.1`

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-K_HipdsW7KXqkdD8F14__YFj-kG0yRQ/view?usp=sharing
This would be the data-set I have trained it on.

Comment: Your neural network will probably not predict 0 and 1 (most often). The output of your neural network is a probability between 0 and 1. This is an approximation of the real probability to observe the positive label (1) knowing you observe X as input. You must set a threshold (let's say 0.5) to predict your final labels. By the way, it seems that your input `train` (resp. `test`) contains the labels... You give to the neural network the answer of the test before letting him to infer the answers :)

Comment: If your goal is to train it to find periodicity in your data, you should probably train on features which include the position within the data.

Comment: It did not predict `6.1`, you need to look for scientific notation. `6.131363e-27` is a very small number.

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted the output wrong.
I added

```
if prediction < 0.5:
  print("It's 0")
else:
  print("It's 1")
```